# Number sort - Gold - Silver - Bronze

Tags: php, html

I got a problem.
I want a working Number sort, thats what I got:

```
$mynumber=7915503;
echo substr($mynumber, 0, 3)." Gold ". substr($mynumber, 3, 2)." Silver " . substr($mynumber, 5, 2)." Bronze ";
```

With that number, it works.
Output: 791 Gold 55 Silver 03 Bronze

But if I change the Number like 9, it will Output: 9 Gold Silver Bronze
I want put the Number 9 in and Output 0 Gold 0 Silver 9 Bronze

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: What would the input be if the output was `9 Silver`?

Answer (score 0):

You could pad the string, e.g. like this:

```
$mynumber = substr("0000000", strlen($mynumber)) . $mynumber;
```

Or if it is an integer:

```
$bronze = $mynumber % 100;
$silver = ($mynumber / 100) % 100;
$gold = $mynumber / 10000;
```

That said, if you have the possibility to change the format how those numbers are stored I would do so. Why not take an array?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the ending, using with substr negatives numbers.
"If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string."